# Script returning PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'error'

Tags: php

I a using a friend's script in WinSCP using putty and when I do 'create' in the script, it returns this error. I need help with this please, my friend is away for a week. it directs me to 'line 86' in the PHP file. I have went ahead and copy and pasted the other lines surrounding line 86 to give a better idea.

**ERROR FACED:**

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'error' in /root/100tb/includes/100tb.php on line 86
>
> Line 86 is -

```
$errorMessage = (isset($result['data']['error']['message']))? $result['data']['error']['message'] : $result['data']['error'];
```

All help appreciated.

```
 }
    }

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    if (isset($response[0])) {
        if ($response[0] == '[' || $response[0] == '{') {
            $response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
        }
    }

    $result = array(
        'data' => $response,
        'info' => curl_getinfo($handle),
    );

    curl_close($handle);

    if ($result['info']['http_code'] !== 200) {
        $errorMessage = (isset($result['data']['error']['message']))? $result['data']['error']['message'] : $result['data']['error'];
        throw new Exception($errorMessage,$result['info']['http_code']);
    }

    return $result['data'];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have decoded `$response`?

Comment: The error message means what it says quite literally: `$result['data']` is a string, not an array, and you are trying to address a position in that string with `'error'`, which cannot succeed in any meaningful way.

Most probably the guard around the decoding step prevents `json_decode` from being called, which would mean the curl-call does not return structured data serialized as json.

Answer (score 0):

> PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'error' in /root/100tb/includes/100tb.php on line 86

means that there isn't the key `error` in the array `$result['data']` when you access it in the line 86, particularly because **`$result['data']` isn't an array**!

I suggest to you to check the whole content of `$result` by var_dump it:

```
var_dump($result);
```

So you can see if it really contains the `error` key or other data.

Comment: No, it means `$result['data']` is not an array, that would be an `Undefined offset: 'error'` message, not `illegal STRING offset`